# ajax-приложение. Проектирование.

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, проектирование, javascript

В голову пришла мысль написать web-приложение по типу десктопного приложения.

В арсенале имеется: 
на сервере: старый добрый php, MySQL server.
на клиенте: javascript + любые js-библиотеки. 
Использование flash, silverlight и прочего им подобного добра в данном проекте невозможно.

Также, думаю, стоит отметить и то, что в будущем планируется создать и аналогичное десктоп-приложение на Flash(Flex)/JavaFX/WPF, которое будет удалённо работать с этой же базой данных. (В качестве примера: существует приложение "Видеолюбитель", ссылка кому интересно посмотреть и/или кто о нем ничего не слышал g8r.ru)

Что думаю я:
Мне понравилась идеалогия описанная на хабре (ссылка http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/php/138245/) Т.к. я на "ты" с kohana, то на серваке с её помощью замутить soapserver и с базой работать с помощью её встроенной ORM. Клиенту отдавать JSON. 
На клиенте: jQuery + jq plugins, вызовы удалённых процедур (JSONP).

В чем беда, чего не знаю: 
Как сделать подмену url при переходах (с этим разберусь - не вопрос. Нагуглил кучу всего: fullajax, pajax) Насколько я понял, суть везде одна: html5 history. Можете подсказать что конкретно нужно использовать чтоб url менялся и роботы сайт индексировали, чтоб можно было смело использовать, а не так что "ну вот вроде страница не перезагружется и url-ы меняются. вроде как и поисковики должны понять что к чему". Хочется обойтись без "вроде как". Прошу подсказать.

Далее: Если у Вас есть практика создания такого типа приложений, то как Вы это реализовывали? С помощью каких библиотек? Как отправляли данные клиенту? (json/xml/html/ещё как-то ?) Может php-фреймворк какой подскажите где эту задачу было бы ловчее реализовать. Как я уже упомянул - сам использую kohana 3.2. Если в ZF-library есть удобные плюшки для реализации api, подскажите куда глянуть.

Итог: вообщем хочу чтобы вы, уважаемое сообщество, научили меня (надеюсь "научили" не слишком громко сказано) что делать со сменой url-ов, и может где-то в чем-то посоветовали хотя бы на уровне в какую сторону смотреть. Заранее Вам благодарен.

Comment: imho, нужно поддержать просто два варианта работы. если url запрашивается через ajax, отдавать одно (json, jsonp и т.д.), если впрямую отдавать страницу целиком. Гугль, например, частично умеет парсить javascript переходы (некоторые довольно сложные), но полагаться на то, что все проиндексируется и так, не стоит... Кроме того, обычный посетитель тоже может зайти по указанному url, следовательно нужно будет отдать всю страницу...

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, ясен пень что ответ аяксу и неаяксу будет разным. Вопрос в том, как быть с УРЛами, что использовать, чего не использовать

Comment: Вот здесь вот почитайте доки описания и т.д. Как я понимаю здесь вы можете найти ответы на все ваши вопросы. [тыц](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для урлов используй pushstate для современных браузеров и хэш для криво-калечных эксплореров. Вид ссылок используй обычный, только при аяксе отменяй действие по умолчанию, так поисковики будут нормально индексировать

Comment: Уже что-то, спасибо. ТОлько что значит вид ссылок использовать обычный? Типа не ЧПУ, а простой index.php?var1=val1&var2=val2... ?

Comment: нет, я имею ввиду что ссылки не должны быь сделаны через хэш